# how to add space for child item in dropdown?

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I'm trying to show the parent child elements in dropdown select list.as the following image[image]

i have the code as in foreach

```
@helper GetOption(List<Project_Cost_Management_System.Models.ChartOfAccount> model1, Guid? parentid) 
{
    foreach (var item3 in model1.Where(s => s.ParentAccountId.Equals(parentid)))
    {


        var zs3 = model1.Where(s => s.ParentAccountId == item3.Id);
        int count3 = zs3.Count();
        if (count3 >= 0)
        {
            if(@item3.ParentAccountId == null)
            { 
             <option value="@item3.Id">@item3.Name</option>
            }
            else
            {
                var cout = model1.Count();
                <option value="@item3.Id"> @item3.Name   @model1.Where(s => s.dataid == @item3.dataparentid).Select(d => d.Name).First(). </option>
            }
        }
        if (count3 > 0)
        {
            @GetOption(model1, item3.Id)
        }

    }
}
```

but it showed as [image]

How can i display as the first picture.

Comment: Can you post a demo of the current output?

Comment: I meant live demo. How can we analyze the code? :) You have a dynamic code.

Comment: why dont you use combo box ? instead of single dropdown?

Comment: can please give me an example.

Comment: @RonakBhatt: A combo box is just a dropdown with a text field attached that allows you to enter free text or pick an existing item. It hardly satisfies anything the OP is looking for here.

Comment: @ChrisPratt any idea then?

Comment: @RonakBhatt i got answer see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got Answer.

Adding another field in model class as Hierarchy.

Adding space using the hierarchy. I add my code for refer.

```
@helper GetOption(List<Project_Cost_Management_System.Models.ChartOfAccount> model1, Guid? parentid)
{

    foreach (var item3 in model1.Where(s => s.ParentAccountId.Equals(parentid)))
    {

        var zs3 = model1.Where(s => s.ParentAccountId == item3.Id);
        int count3 = zs3.Count();
        if (count3 >= 0)
        {
            if (@item3.ParentAccountId == null)
            {
                <option value="@item3.Id">@item3.Name</option>
            }
            else
            {
                int str = @item3.Hierarchy * 3;
                string str1 = " ".ToString().PadRight(str);
                str1 = str1.Replace(" ", "\u00a0");
                <option value="@item3.Id">@str1 @item3.Name</option>

            }
        }
        if (count3 > 0)
        {
            @GetOption(model1, item3.Id)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of achieve what you're looking for using `<optgroup>`, so your rendered HTML would end up being something like:

```
<option value="...">Professional Fees</option>
<optgroup label="Property Related Expenses">
    <option value="...">Maintenance Contribution</option>
    ...
</optgroup>
...
```

The only problem you might have with this, is that your actual groupings are not valid options themselves, i.e. you can't pick "Property Related Expenses", because it's just a grouping label. You also can't really control your right aligned descriptive text this way. In general, the HTML `select` element is pretty restrictive and doesn't allow a whole lot of customization.

When you need more advance functionality, you must move some sort of library that creates a "control" that mimics the functionality of a select list with more customizable HTML elements. There's a million and one different such libraries out on the interwebs, but I'm particular fond of [Select2.js](https://select2.github.io/examples.html). In particular to your scenario, see the section there on "Templating".

Comment: If I used opgrop means how can i make option group is selected value because parent is also children of some.

Comment: You can't. That's the point. I was merely pointing out that optgroup is the best you can do with straight HTML and that is  insufficient. You're going to have to use some sort of JS solution for this.